# Google Places API for iOS not displaying PriceLevel, Rating, and OpenStatus

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, response, google-places-api

I recently implemented Google Places API into an app I am working on, and I've been able to make calls to receive places nearby and through query with ease. However, when reading the data I receive, all information is present except the PriceLevel and Rating always return 0 and the OpenStatus always returns 2.

Here is an example of the output I receive:

```
Place name: Supermarket, id: identifier, coordinate: (40, -73), open now: 2, phone: +1 718-555-1020, address: Address City, NY, United States, rating: 0.000000, price level: 0, website: http://www.website.com/, types: (
"grocery_or_supermarket",
food,
store,
"point_of_interest",
establishment
)
```

I changed the data to hide the identity of the establishment for this example. As you can see, it is returning 0.00000 for rating, and 0 for price level consistently, along with 2 for open now.

Anyone have an idea as to why?

Comment: Would it be because of the place? try search the same place with the [web api](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/search) to see if it is just bad data or an actual bug in the iOS API.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I checked using the Google Places web api which worked fine. However the iOS API is still giving me trouble

Comment: @kaho forgot to mention